# turning "would have" sentences into questions

Tags: questions, conditional-constructions

Can you turn "would have" sentences into questions? I don't think I've ever heard people use it to ask questions. Is "would have" strictly for answering questions or conditionals? Here are some examples I've come up with:

> I wouldn't have told you if I weren't going to tell you.

Turning this into a question:

> Would I have told you if I weren't going to tell you?

Another example:

> If I hadn't done it, I wouldn't have boasted about it.

Turning this into a question form:

> Would I have boasted about it if I hadn't done it?

Are these constructions possible?

Comment: Maybe "Would I have told you if I **hadn't (already) planned {on telling/to tell}** you?" or "Would I have told you **had I not (already) planned {on telling/to tell}** you?" would be better. You've already done what you asked about, so you've answered your own question. This kind of question is natural & idiomatic English.

Answer (score 2):

Those constructions are natural and idiomatic.

However, for me, the first example,

> I wouldn't have told you if I weren't going to tell you.

required me to reread it, since I initially parsed the sentence with:

> to tell <somebody> <something>

instead of

> to tell <somebody>.

By rearranging the parts of that phrase, it gets rid of that confusion;

> If I weren't going to tell you, I wouldn't have told you.

---

You can similarly change positive "would have" statements into questions.

So,

> If it had been sunny yesterday, he would have gone to the movies.

and

> He would have gone to the movies if it had been sunny yesterday.

can be transformed into:

> Would he have gone to the movies if it had been sunny yesterday?